# Why does Postgres refuse to use a composite index in some setups?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, composite

So, I have a table that looks like:

```
                                 Table "public.rule_traffic"
          Column       |  Type   |                       Modifiers
     id                | bigint  | not null default nextval('rule_traffic_seq'::regclass)
     device_id         | integer | not null
     version_id        | integer | not null
     policy_name       | text    |
     rule_uid          | uuid    | not null
     traffic_hash_code | bigint  | not null
     action            | integer |
```

along with these indexes:

```
"rule_traffic_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"unique_device_id_version_id_policy_name_uid_in_rule_traffic" UNIQUE, btree (device_id, version_id, policy_name, rule_uid)
```

when I run a test query on my setup(and many others) , it looks like i'm actually using the defined index unique_device_id_version_id_policy_name_uid_in_rule_traffic :

```
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
HashAggregate  (cost=8.29..8.30 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=1.563..1.563 rows=0 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using unique_device_id_version_id_policy_name_uid_in_rule_traffic on rule_traffic this_  (cost=0.00..8.28 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=1.558..1.558 rows=0 loops=1)
     Index Cond: ((device_id = 11) AND (policy_name IS NULL))
     Filter: ((rule_uid = 'f6c0dc29-e741-4f9a-adf1-f11d18768af3'::uuid) OR (rule_uid = 'c1a12087-2d85-4e44-a115-f9cad7ec915e'::uuid))
Total runtime: 1.704 ms
```

but there is a setup with a totally different query plan (sequence scan):

```
                                                                                    QUERY PLAN
HashAggregate  (cost=150538.23..150538.25 rows=2 width=56) (actual time=2403.600..2403.601 rows=2 loops=1)
->  Seq Scan on rule_traffic this_  (cost=0.00..150538.20 rows=4 width=56) (actual time=2354.481..2403.573 rows=2 loops=1)
     Filter: ((policy_name IS NULL) AND (device_id = 11) AND ((rule_uid = 'f6c0dc29-e741-4f9a-adf1-f11d18768af3'::uuid) OR (rule_uid = 'c1a12087-2d85-4e44-a115-f9cad7ec915e'::uuid)))
Total runtime: 2403.661 ms
```

I've tried running VACUUM FULL\ANALYZE on the table with no results.

Does anyone have any idea why postgres decides not to use the composite index?

UPDATE 1:

tried forcing not to use sequence scan:

```
securetrack=# explain analyze select max(this_.id) as y0_, this_.rule_uid as y1_, this_.policy_name as y2_ from rule_traffic this_ where this_.device_id=11 and ((this_.rule_uid='f6c0dc29-e741-4f9a-adf1-f11d18768af3' and this_.policy_name is null) OR (this_.rule_uid = 'c1a12087-2d85-4e44-a115-f9cad7ec915e' and this_.policy_name is null)) group by this_.rule_uid, this_.policy_name;

QUERY PLAN
 HashAggregate  (cost=209498.38..209498.40 rows=2 width=56) (actual time=2475.980..2475.981 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on rule_traffic this_  (cost=0.00..209498.35 rows=4 width=56) (actual time=1631.945..2475.950 rows=3 loops=1)
     Filter: ((policy_name IS NULL) AND (device_id = 11) AND ((rule_uid = 'f6c0dc29-e741-4f9a-adf1-f11d18768af3'::uuid) OR (rule_uid = 'c1a12087-2d85-4e44-a115-f9cad7ec915e'::uuid)))
 Total runtime: 2476.038 ms
(4 rows)
```

SETTING seqscan = false:

```
securetrack=# SET enable_seqscan=false;
SET
securetrack=# explain analyze select max(this_.id) as y0_, this_.rule_uid as y1_, this_.policy_name as y2_ from rule_traffic this_ where this_.device_id=11 and ((this_.rule_uid='f6c0dc29-e741-4f9a-adf1-f11d18768af3' and this_.policy_name is null) OR (this_.rule_uid = 'c1a12087-2d85-4e44-a115-f9cad7ec915e' and this_.policy_name is null)) group by this_.rule_uid, this_.policy_name;
                                                                                           QUERY PLAN
 HashAggregate  (cost=371469.08..371469.10 rows=2 width=56) (actual time=2936.608..2936.610 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on rule_traffic this_  (cost=197981.02..371469.05 rows=4 width=56) (actual time=2308.843..2936.577 rows=3 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: ((device_id = 11) AND (policy_name IS NULL))
     Filter: ((rule_uid = 'f6c0dc29-e741-4f9a-adf1-f11d18768af3'::uuid) OR (rule_uid = 'c1a12087-2d85-4e44-a115-f9cad7ec915e'::uuid))
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on unique_device_id_version_id_policy_name_uid_in_rule_traffic  (cost=0.00..197981.02 rows=5774287 width=0) (actual time=1283.603..1283.603 rows=5849739 loops=1)
           Index Cond: ((device_id = 11) AND (policy_name IS NULL))
 Total runtime: 2936.680 ms
(7 rows)
```

looks like the cost is actually higher.
How could it be?

Comment: Strange, can you try what happens if you do `SET enable_seqscan=false;` before running on your query? If it still does a sequential scan than there is some reason it cannot use the index otherwise it only thought it was a bad idea. BTW which postgresql version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL is doing the Right Thing here.

If you look at the query plan where you forced it to use the index, you'll see that the index scan finds 5849739 rows with `(device_id = 11) AND (policy_name IS NULL)`, all of which have to be rechecked with the table.

Now scanning such a big part of the index and rechecking all the table rows found is more expensive than a sequential scan of the whole table (sequential reads are usually faster than random access reads).

It is instructive to use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` because that will show you the actual number of database blocks accessed.